# Iterator on a vector invalidated if another thread pushes an element on the end the vector?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, mutex

I was wondering if I need a mutex lock in this case.

I have a vector `my_vector` that is operated on by two threads.

Thread 1:

```
my_vector.push_back(element)
// send a request for the element, the subject of which thread 2 will receive
// continues
```

Thread 2:

```
// receive element
iter = my_vector.find(element) // This **will** be found in the vector
// do stuff using iter
```

My question is: it is possible that thread 1 could add more elements to `my_vector` whilst thread 2 is using `iter`... but should this matter? If items are only added to the end of the vector, surely the iterator looking at the element in the middle won't be affected?

Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Comment: If push_back causes the vector to exceed its capacity, the vector will reallocate to a new, larger buffer, move over the old data and then delete the old buffer. So your old iterators point to deleted data if that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely to be affected eventually.

Vectors work by moving memory around. Whenever you add an element to a vector whose memory is full, the existing elements are first copied to newly allocated, larger memory and then the element is added. Then the original memory is destroyed. So any iterators pointing to the original memory are invalidated.

Comment: I didn't realise vectors were 'resized' like this. I now understand Mr Schwartz' sound advice to veer on the side of caution/locks when it comes to simultaneous access. Thanks.

Comment: @ricky116 No problem. Note, vectors behave this way because of the requirement to hold elements contiguously in memory. The resizing doesn't happen with e.g. linked lists.

Comment: @maditya - but adding to a linked list modifies internal pointers, and that will screw up reads from another thread. If one thread modifies the contents of an object while another thread is reading or modifying the same object you have a data race, and the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're right of course, when multiple threads are involved the access must be synchronized in order to prevent data races regardless of the container. To be clear, the distinction I pointed out between vectors and lists (i.e., adding an element to a vector may cause iterators to other elements of the vector, to be invalidated, but this is not the case for a list) holds for _sequential_ programs.

Answer (score 3):

You are required to use a lock if an object may be accessed in one thread while it's modified in another.

> but should this matter? If items are only added to the end of the vector, surely the iterator looking at the element in the middle won't be affected?

Don't reason like this. It will cause nothing but pain. Stick to things that are guaranteed to work rather than doing things that you think should work because you can't think of any way they could go wrong. An obvious case -- what if the `push_back` resizes the vector?